# Windows 10 missing WSL Linux icon in navigation pane

Tags: windows-10

Why is there no Linux icon showing up in the Windows 10 navigation pane? 
I followed the solution suggested in [Add or Remove Linux from Navigation Pane in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/127506-add-remove-linux-navigation-pane-windows-10-a.html), but I had no luck.

All the settings are enabled.

WSL enabled:

[image: WSL enabled]

Windows 10 Navigation pane:

[image: Navigation pane]

Windows 10 details:
Education, Version 1909 (OS build 18363.815).

Comment: I am also having same problem. I run the Add linux.reg in the link you show, and it had no effect at all. Linux icon still do not show. I am running latest and greatest version of windows 10

Answer (score 1):

You are a bit early, this will happen in the next major Windows update.
It is at the moment called Windows 10 build 19603, just now rolling out to
Fast Ring Insiders.

Older methods are probably already non-functional, as Microsoft is building
up to this release.

See the Microsoft announcement at
[Announcing Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 19603](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2020/04/08/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-19603/).

[image]

**EDIT**: This option has disappeared. Now it's required to
enter `\\wsl$\` into the address-bar. Afterward, a new entry
named `wsl$` will be displayed below Network, up until this
Explorer instance is closed.

Sometimes even that will not work, and one needs to also add
the name of the Linux distribution, like `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-20.04`.

Comment: I am confused by the Windows 10 build numbers. I have upgraded to Windows 10 21H2 and the build number is 19044.1586. I would expect it to be higher than the preview build 19603 mentioned above as the first preview of 21H2 was a long time later - on 2021-07-15. What is this mess in the build numbers? --- Anyway I do not have the Linux icon in the File Explorer although I have read that it should be one of features of 21H2.

Comment: See the [List of Microsoft Windows versions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Microsoft_Windows_versions). The WSL interface is still evolving and not yet fully implemented, and its implementation is continuing only in Windows 11. The Windows 10 version of WSL is all but frozen.

Comment: I am running windows 10 pro  21H2 build 19044.1645 with WSL 2 installed and active, but I also do not see the linux icon anywhere.

Comment: @Nasser: See my addition to the answer. Microsoft changes its interface too fast, so even answers of one or two years ago may no longer be entirely correct.

Comment: I know I can access it by typing `\\wsl$` in the address bar of explorer. and it does show up. But not under the network. The problem is that when I am inside another app on windows, like Maple, it does not see the Linux file system. Here is screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4fUF.png)  and here is screen shot of my explorer. ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPss9.png)  if an app can't see it from windows, I can't navigate to it and open files.

Comment: If the application uses the Windows file dialog, you may be able to right click the WSL entry that you see and "Pin to Quick access". If it doesn't, you may be able to add it or its shortcut in other places that the application can access.